# Counting Only the First Entry of Data in a Column that can have Duplicate Values

Tags: mysql, excel, unique, counting

I want to be able to count only the first entry/line for each unique transaction for each register (see example table below). E.g. for 1234, count 1 child but do not count the adult or the second child.

Transaction No. Register    Adult   Child

```
1234        A           0       1       

1234        A           1       0           

1234        A           0       1           

3456        B           1       0           

5678        B           1       0

2468        C           1       0

2468        C           0       1
```

The resulting table I expect to get is:

Trans No.   Adlts   Chld

```
A           0       1

B           2       0

C           1       0
```

I can count the number of unique transaction numbers using the formula:

```
=COUNT(IF(FREQUENCY(A2:A8,A2:A8)>0,1))
```

I can also count the count the total number of adults and children who have paid at each register. E.g. counting the number of adults who paid at till C:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B8,”C”,C2:C8,1)
```

Or an array formula (counting number of adults for all transaction numbers:

```
{=COUNTIFS(B2:B8,F2:F5,C2:C8,”=1”)}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask](http://www.stackoverflow/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an additional dummy variable to the data (column D in the example)as ascending numbers (1-7 in example):

```
1234    A   0   1   1
1234    A   1   0   2
1234    A   0   1   3
3456    B   1   0   4
5678    B   1   0   5
2468    C   1   0   6
2468    C   0   1   7
```

Placing your desired resulting table in Cell G2

```
H2 Formula: ={INDEX($B$2:$D$8,LARGE(--(G2=$B$2:$B$8)*($E$2:$E$8),SUM(--(G2=$B$2:$B$8))),2)}
I2 Formula: ={INDEX($B$2:$D$8,LARGE(--(G2=$B$2:$B$8)*($E$2:$E$8),SUM(--(G2=$B$2:$B$8))),3)}
```

Not an ideal solution, but tested and works.